# Variable in custom class always prints 0

Tags: java, class, methods

So I'm super new to programming. I've created a simple Calc class that get 2 numbers though it's constructor. I created a calcTotal `method` that adds these two numbers together and puts them in a variable called total. I then created a printTotal method which is nothing but System.out.println(total);

However when I create a object in main and call the printTotal method, It always prints out 0. I understand total is initialized to 0 in my Calc class. I don't understand how to pass the calculated total from the calcTotal method to the printTotal method. If I place System.out.println(total) in the calcTotal method an call the in main I get the correct total.

hetes my Calc class

```
public class Calc{

private int numOne;
private int numTwo;
private int total;

 public Calc(int numOne, int numTwo){
    this.numOne = numOne;
    this.numTwo = numTwo;
 }

   public void calcTotal(){

    total = numOne + numTwo;

 }

  public void printTotal(){

    System.out.println(total);
 }
}
```

and my main

```
public class HelloWorld{

 public static void main(String []args){

    Calc myCalc = new Calc(3,5);
    myCalc.printTotal();

 }
}
```

I know it's a super beginner question and it'll probably get downvoted but it's frustrating me.

Thank you for any help

Comment: "*I created a calcTotal class*". you didn't create a `class`. you create a `method` calcTotal.

Comment: Thanks I didn't notice that typo

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You never call `calcTotal()`, the method that does the calculation, before calling the printing method, and so the sum is never calculated.

But regardless, you shouldn't have two methods like so, as this error can be easily prevented by instead just having `calcTotal()` return the int value, and then the calling code can print it, or do whatever it wants with it.

```
public int calcTotal() {
    return numOne + numTwo;
}
```

in main:

```
Calc myCalc = new Calc(3,5);
System.out.println("total: " + myCalc.calcTotal());
```

Comment: Shouldn't it return an `int`?

Comment: Nice answer though!

Comment: Thanks for your help. I know it was a stupid questiom

Answer (score 3):

You never calculate the total before printing it. Your main should look like this.

```
public class HelloWorld{

 public static void main(String []args){

    Calc myCalc = new Calc(3,5);
    myCalc.calcTotal();
    myCalc.printTotal();

 }
}
```

You might want to consider to add the calcTotal() function to your constructor.

```
 public Calc(int numOne, int numTwo){
    this.numOne = numOne;
    this.numTwo = numTwo;
    calcTotal();
 }
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer I upvoted yes since I can't choose more then one correct